# Filter out command line options before passing to a program

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ld

I am running `cmake` and it is passing a flag to my linker that is unrecognized (`-rdynamic`), and it's causing an error.
I cannot figure out where it is getting this flag from, so I want to just filter it out.

I can specify `-DCMAKE_LINKER=<linker>`, so what I would like to do is set `<linker>` to a program that reads its command line arguments, filters out the bad one, and then passes the result back to the actual linker.

I have been using `awk '{gsub("-rdynamic", "");print}'`, but I don't know to make the input stdin and the output ld.

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! Can't you edit directly `CMakeLists.txt` and remove the offending flag? That said, if it's there, there should be a good reason...

Comment: Do you really mean "reads from stdin"?  It sounds like you need a wrapper script that takes any number of command-line arguments, drops "-rdynamic" if it's one of them, and invokes the linker with the rest.

Comment: I don't think that "filtering out" the option is the correct thing to do. It would be better to make CMake detect the correct options to use. This is after all what CMake is _supposed_ to do.

Comment: I can edit `CMakeLists.txt`, but the problem is that I can't figure out where the flag is coming from.  I grepped everything for the flag or similar keywords but there is nothing explicitly adding it.  I am also pretty sure that -rdynamic is a flag intended for the compiler, the linker flag is --export-dynamic, so it may actually be a bug in the cmake files.

Comment: @JigglyNaga this is an apt description of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `bash` script loops through its arguments, ignoring those matching the string "`-rdynamic`", and adding any others to an array.  Once it runs out of arguments, it executes `ld` with the filtered list.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a finalopts
finalopts=()

for o in "$@"; do
    if [ "$o" = "-rdynamic" ] ; then
        continue
    fi
    #add all other options to the list
    finalopts+=("$o")
done

exec ld "${finalopts[@]}"
```

Comment: Awesome.  This is exactly what I was trying to do.